# Can we say that an electronic relay works as DC to AC converter or am I misunderstanding how to read a relay's markings?

Tags: relay

I don't understand the "16 A / 250 V ~" marking, what does that mean? Is it the output of the relay?

If so, can we say that the relay works with 12 V DC and gives as an output 250 V AC?

Plus, I don't understand the "16 A". Is it the maximum current that the relay can output or does it give literally 16 A AC?

Please I am newbie to electronics and I am trying to understand this component, so I hope you can help me out here with a good explanation.

[image: photo of relay]

Comment: No conversion between AC and DC. 12 V DC is the coil rating. 250 V AC is the contact rating. They are two separate things. 16 A is the maximum current the contact can withstand.

Comment: a relay is an electrically operated switch ... it does not generate power ... think of a light switch on your wall ... instead of using your finger to flip the switch, a solenoid is used to flip the switch

Answer (score 3):

No, a relay is simply an electrically controlled switch.

In a mechanical relay there is an electro-magnet, a coil of wire around an iron or steel pole piece. When current passes through through the coil the pole piece is magnetized and attracts an armature, which moves the contacts of a switch.

In a solid state relay the switching is done electronically instead of mechanically.

Depending on the type of relay the coil can be designed for either AC or DC current and the switch contacts can be rated for AC or DC current and voltage, or they can be rated for both AC and DC.

So a relay can be used to switch AC with DC, DC with AC, DC with DC or AC with AC, depending on the design.

Answer (score 1):

It means the coil is driven by 12 V DC and the contacts can bear a load of up to 250 V AC at 16 A.

There is no conversion, it just switches an AC load by a DC voltage on the coil.

You might be interested in reading [how a relay works](https://www.electronicshub.org/what-is-relay-and-how-it-works/); also, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n594CkrP6xE) can be insightful.

Comment: Okay I get it, however just a lil confused about the definition of a switch, So Relay act as a switch and as u said the contact can bear a load of up to 250V ac at 16A, I guess my question here is a switch between who and who ? hypothetically speaking lets assume were in a PCB, so the Relay switch is usually between a source which is the AC power source and the load which is a motor ? so the relay comes in between them to act a switch ???

Comment: @Samantha a relay is between a source and a load - correct. And there will be a coil that will be used to control it (that is, the load will either receive current or not).

Answer (score 1):

What you are holding is not an electronic relay but a mechanical relay. It has a coil of wire which, when energized, causes a switch to close. The relay coil requires 12 volts of DC to activate the switch closure. The contacts of the switch (which is a single-pole single-throw type indicated by the 1A designation) can handle up to 16 amperes of current and 250 volts AC. Relays do not convert from DC to AC. However they do allow, as in this case, a DC voltage to control the application of an AC voltage.

Answer (score 1):

### Your Coil Relay is DC

The [Omron G2RL](https://omronfs.omron.com/en_US/ecb/products/pdf/en-g2rl.pdf) is a coil relay. One good way to tell is to look for a table like this:

[image]

Finding a **Coil** table is a dead give-away. And then reading that there is a *coil resistance* column pretty much nails it down.

There are other kinds of relays. But this is a very specific category.

### Coil Relays: AC and DC

Here's an example of two such relays, one from Siemens and used in old copper telephone relay systems:

[image]

The coil on the left requires a power supply in order to activate it. These coils are designed in one of two different ways: (1) Applied DC voltage; or, (2) Applied AC voltage. If AC, then it will be a shaded-pole type. You don't have to worry about that detail, but a [shaded-construction](https://www.nutsvolts.com/questions-and-answers/ac-relays-are-a-shady-deal) is how the AC coil is made to work as intended. For DC, it's just a typical electromagnet that you can build easily at home.

Either way, when the coil is activated with an appropriate power source then an arm is pulled towards one end of the coil and this causes a section of the switches on the right to move enough to either make or break contacts. If you look closely, you should see some metal pads towards the upper right and just at the ends of some metal *leaves*. You should see a tiny gap there. That means this switch is open without power to the coil. When power is applied, those pads will be made to touch each other, causing the switch to close and allow current.

Below is a much larger relay designed to handle 40 Amps of AC:

[image]

But in this case the coil is an AC coil and designed to work directly with mains voltages.

### Other Coil Relay Types

There are other kinds of coil relays than what I've already mentioned.

For example, there are coil relays that have an added mechanism to help them latch into one position or another so that if coil power is removed they can "remember" where they were last positioned. But the common coil relays aren't latching and are either powered or unpowered to choose the state you want.

And there will be about as many different kinds of coil relays as there are applications and the imagination to achieve them. So, while you can generally assume some things about a coil relay lacking other information, you should remain aware that you may very well encounter a new type you've not yet seen.

### Coil Relay Specifications

I won't get much into this. Just making a few basic points.

A coil relay has two basic sections:

- The coil section which is either powered or unpowered. There will be a specification telling you what range of conditions are required in order to power it. (Unpowered is kind of obvious -- don't power it.) The specifications for powering the coil section will let you know how much power is required for holding the relay, once engaged, as well as what's needed to get it engaged in the first place. (These may be slightly different, as the power needed to get it going and moving into position may be more than what's required to hold it there once it is in position.)
- The switch section which is either in its inactive state (when the coil is unpowered) or in its active state (when the coil is powered.) The switch section will have its own set of specifications, too. The switch section may also have current and power specifications. But these will be about what they can handle. Although current and power may also be specified for the coil section, these have nothing to do with each other. You need to keep these separated in mind.

That's about it. Just seeing them, physically, should give you a good idea.

And you can always just build one at home, too. They are NOT rocket science. And once you fabricate your own relay, even if you throw it away afterwards, none of these specifications will ever again be confusing. You will know in your gut what they mean. And it doesn't take a lot of work to try it for yourself. So, if you ever feel like it, do it!